# webpage does not recieve data passed by another webpage

Tags: javascript, html

`<a href="#"  data-role="2" data-champ="0">...</a>`

pass data:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cardctn a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const champdata = $(this).data('champ');

        window.location.href = 'profile.html?data-champ=' + champdata;
    })
})
```

*get data:

```
function getQueryParam(name) {
    const urlparams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    return urlparams.get(name);
}

let datachamp = parseInt(getQueryParam('data-champ'));

let file = "./json/"+ dataarray[datachamp] + ".json"; // call file based on the passed value
```

when this was still in a local machine, everything worked fine but when it was deployed using github, it doesnt work as intended to

i don't have any idea what to do as this is my first time deploying a website

Comment: Are you sure the data transfer is the point of failure and not the path to the JSON file?

Comment: Why would this need to involve JavaScript in the first place? Why do you not make your link `href` point to `profile.html?data-champ=0` to begin with?

Comment: Do you see `?data-champ=0` in the location bar when it redirects?